# Query Failed Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I am using Standard SQL.Even though its a basic query it is still throwing errors. Any suggestions pls

```
SELECT 
  fullVisitorId,
  CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS string),CAST(visitId AS string)) AS session,
  date,
  visitStartTime,
  hits.time,
  hits.page.pagepath
FROM
  `XXXXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20160801"
  AND "20170331"
ORDER BY
  fullVisitorId,
  date,
  visitStartTime
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way for this query to work is by removing the ordering applied in the end:

```
SELECT 
  fullVisitorId,
  CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS string),CAST(visitId AS string)) AS session,
  date,
  visitStartTime,
  hits.time,
  hits.page.pagepath
FROM
  `XXXXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20160801"
  AND "20170331"
```

`ORDER BY` operation is quite expensive and cannot be processed in parallel so try to avoid it (or try applying it in a limited result set)

Comment: Thanks Willian. It's working, but can you tell me the reason why it was not working when I use order by.

Comment: There were too many rows to hold in memory on a single node. If you look at the "Explanation" tab for the query, it will show where it ran out of memory.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottBrossard

Comment: I encountered the same issue. Even weirder, the query succeeded in the web UI but not in the python API. Removed ORDER BY clauses solved the issue but it's a bit weird to experience the discrepancy.

Comment: I know this isa bit old, but does `OVER (PARTITION BY ...` has the same effect?

Answer (score 3):

Besides the accepted answer, you might want to partition your table by date to lessen the amount of memory used with an expensive query.

Comment: The above query is to pull the GA data and by default it is partitioned by date.
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20160801"
  AND "20170331"

This is how I am pulling data from different date ranges

Answer (score 1):

To avoid gathering big chunk into a slot, you can try:

1. Split the data into small chunks before querying,
2. Use a `LIMIT` clause with an `ORDER BY` operation, or
3. Remove the `ORDER BY` operation from the query.

Please refer to the GCP documentations regarding the error:
[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-output#use_a_limit_clause_with_large_sorts
[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#resourcesExceeded