# The query could not be executed in the allotted memory

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a simple query to run :

```
update`dataset.mytable`
set field_1 = cast( field_2 as int64) 
where field_2 not in ('AA', 'BB')
```

And I got the error:

> Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory..

The table has only 1 billion rows...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query Failed Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005418/query-failed-error-resources-exceeded-during-query-execution-the-query-could-n)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This is a different issue; there is no explicit ORDER BY. bignano, can you share a sample job ID that demonstrates the failure? I'd like to look more into what happened.

Comment: Can you try running your query again? There is currently a [bug related to loading large files](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67890371) that seems like it caused problems here, but I was able to run a process over your table that should have resolved it in this particular case.

Comment: oh great. you have fixed it. what magic did you perform? Also I ran a query earlier on this same table joining another table of the same size, and it took 7227.9s to complete, is that normal?

Comment: I'm glad that worked! I'll add an answer explaining in more detail. It could be that the problem with the table made joining slower than it should have been too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really was a bug, similar to [this report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67890371). There wasn't a way for you to know in this case, but if you do find a bug in the future, you can [submit it to the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) since the broader StackOverflow community probably can't help.

As a summary of what happened:

- It looks like the files loaded to the table were quite large, e.g. multiple gigabytes in size each. Loading smaller files would not have triggered the BigQuery bug.
- When persisting the contents of these files to BigQuery storage, BigQuery did not sufficiently shard the table (this is the bug on BigQuery's side of things).
- When executing the `UPDATE` statement, BigQuery tried to execute a large amount of work across only a small number of partitions, leading to the `Resources exceeded` message.
- I was able to fix the problem by manually instructing BigQuery storage to reshard your table. This is something that isn't exposed through the BigQuery API, since it shouldn't be necessary unless there is a bug.

Comment: I think it is in our best interests  to keep this SO clean and comply with site's rules. If it were me - i would just create respective issue on behalf of OP on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/ and dealt with this Q there. Just wanted to share my thoughts with you - who I respect a lot, so hope you will not get this personally! :o)

Comment: I think it's fine just to close the question now. There is a bug that the OP can use to track the underlying issue, and I was able to help resolve the immediate problem in any case. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for support/understanding I still voted up your answer as you well deserved it :o)

Comment: Thank you for the input. I wonder what you mean by the files loaded to the table, the table in this question was created by joining two previous tables. Do you refer to the original files in GCS loaded into the BigQuery table ?  When do you expect such bug be fixed, and before the bug fixed, how can I prevent this from happening on my side?

Comment: Also I just wonder if I export the big table into GCS and reload them into BigQuery, will that solve the problem since i notice the export function will create  massively split small files in GCS.

Comment: Please follow up on the bug that I linked to and someone should be able to help explain more.